# How to get total count of result in OData-WebApi without changing the structure of actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

So, I want to apply $inlinecount for my webapi project.
My api controller is like this:

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
     {
         // GET api/values
         [Queryable(PageSize = 1)]
         public IQueryable<string> Get()
         {
             return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" }.AsQueryable();
         }
     }
```

But, I don't want to change the structure of action to this:

```
public PageResult<string> Get(ODataQueryOptions<string> queryOptions)
{
    IQueryable results = queryOptions.ApplyTo(values.AsQueryable());
    return new PageResult<string>(results as IEnumerable<string>, Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());
}
```

Is it possible to QueryableAttribute for this purpose? If yes, how?

Comment: According to this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options your first sample should just work???

Comment: No, it doesn't return the total count in the json result.

Comment: api/category?$filter=Id eq 1212&$inlinecount=allpages but it return normal result.